# How to get index of selected option outside the select in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-material

I have a simple `<select>` in Angular (with Material) as follows:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Type</mat-label>
  <mat-select placeholder="Type" formControlName="type" name="type" id="name">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of types" [value]="t">
      {{t}} <-- it is enum -->
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I would like to use index of selected type in the other part of code.

To be more precise: in `*ngFor` of another select. Therefore, I can't use documentById.

In addition, I don't want to install jQuery just for do this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by [**this Angular Material Documentation example**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value), you can bind to **`[(value)]`** two ways:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of types; let i = index" [value]="i">{{t}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

`selected` will be a property on your class.

Here's a [**Working StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/angular/moyolgqgbjgv?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts) from the Angular Team for your reference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately I have to send value of type in post request, so in my case I can't use this solution...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set **`[(ngModel)]`** variable and use the variable to get your index

```
<mat-select placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="selected" formControlName="type" name="type" id="name">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of types" [value]="t">
      {{t}} <-- it is enum -->
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

and then in the component, use

```
this.index = this.types.findIndex(item => item === selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Sajeetharans answer, using `ngModel` together with reactive form is not recommended, and is also deprecated. Instead watch for the changes of the form control and find the index and store it in a variable for later use. Here's a sample:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

idx: number;
foods = ['Steak', 'pizza-1'];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    mySelect: ['']
  });

  this.myForm.get('mySelect').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
    this.idx = this.foods.findIndex(val => val === value);
    console.log(this.idx)
  });
}
```